# Linux - reading from serial port error in C (Resource temporarily unavaliable)

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I am trying to read some data from serial port using usb/rs232 converter. I am sending data from atmega and it is received properly in minicom. But trying to read sth in my program ends up with an error "Resource temporarily unavailable". I know that this is caused by O_NDELAY, but removing that gives me plenty of empty messages which also isn't good.

Actually, what I want to achieve is a program, which every second will transmit some char to atmega and wait for a response. Depending on a response it will do different actions. Also after few unanswered transmissions program will indicate an error with communication.

But for now I'd like to at least receive something properly.

Here is my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int fd; //file descriptor
int bytes; // bytes to read

int PortOpen(void)
{
    fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if(fd < 0)
    {
        //opening error
        printf("Port opening error\r\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Port opened\r\n");
        //port config
        struct termios options;
        tcgetattr(fd, &options);

        cfsetispeed(&options, B9600);
        cfsetospeed(&options, B9600);

        options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
        options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
        options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
        options.c_cflag |= CS8;
        options.c_cflag |= CLOCAL;
        options.c_cflag |= CREAD;
        options.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

        options.c_cc[VMIN]   =  0;                  
        options.c_cc[VTIME]  =  5;                  

        options.c_lflag &=  ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
        //Modifying c_iflag by bitwise OR and AND
        options.c_iflag &=  ~(ICRNL | INLCR | IGNCR | IUCLC);
        options.c_iflag &=  ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
        //Modifying c_oflag by bitwise OR and AND
        options.c_oflag &=  ~OPOST;
        tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
        //Setting the new settings for the port immediately
        tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);
    }
    return 1;

}

int PortRead(void)
{
    int n = 0, spot = 0;
    char buf = '\0';

    /* Whole response*/
    char response[1024];
    memset(response, '\0', sizeof response);

    do {
        n = read( fd, &buf, 1 );
        sprintf( &response[spot], "%c", buf );
        spot += n;
    } while( buf != '\r' && n > 0);

    if (n < 0) 
    {
        printf("Error reading: %s\r\n",strerror(errno));
    }
    else if (n == 0) 
    {
        printf("Read nothing!\r\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Response: %s", response);
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    PortOpen();
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<100; j++) //just testing
    {
        PortRead();
    }


return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `read()` block when not set to `O_NDELAY/O_NONBLOCK`? Either way, I'd look at `poll()` or `select()` if I were you.

Comment: Just a hint: `char response[1024] = { 0 };`, no need for `memset`.

Comment: strongly suggest using select() control a loop so read() doesn't ever get called unless that is at least 1 char to be read.

Comment: Note: no protection from buffer overrun of `char response[1024];` in `PortRead()`.